# How is separated route used within a main route in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my very first time using React and I don't know how to organize AdminRoutes into the Main App function. I have been looking for the correct code, but haven't found it. Or am I just misunderstanding react-router v6? Could you help me please?

```
function AdminRoutes() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='admin' element={<MainLayout />}>
             <Route index element={<DashBoard />} />
             <Route path='product-lists' element={<ProductList />} />
             <Route path='add-product' element={<AddProduct />} />
             <Route path='edit-product/:id' element={<AddProduct />} />
             <Route path='add-blog' element={<AddBlog />} />
             <Route path='edit-blog/:id' element={<AddBlog />} />
             <Route path='blog-list' element={<BlogList />} />
             <Route path='add-blog-category' element={<AddBlogCategory />} />
                     <Route path='edit-blog-category/:id' element={<AddBlogCategory />} />
             <Route path='blog-category-list' element={<BlogCategoryList />} />
             <Route path='orders' element={<Orders />} />
             <Route
              path='view-orders/:userId/:transitionId'
              element={<ViewOrders />}
             />
                 <Route path='customers' element={<Customers />} />
             <Route path='color-lists' element={<Colors />} />
             <Route path='add-color' element={<AddColor />} />
             <Route path='edit-color/:id' element={<AddColor />} />
             <Route path='category-lists' element={<CategoryList />} />
             <Route path='add-category' element={<AddCategory />} />
             <Route path='edit-category/:id' element={<AddCategory />} />
             <Route path='brand-lists' element={<BrandList />} />
             <Route path='add-product-brand' element={<AddBrand />} />
             <Route path='edit-product-brand/:id' element={<AddBrand />} />
             <Route path='add-coupon' element={<AddCoupon />} />
             <Route path='coupon-lists' element={<CouponList />} />
             <Route path='inquiry' element={<Inquiry />} />
             <Route path='view-inquiry/:id' element={<ViewInquiry />} />
             <Route path='specific-data' element={<SpecificDataPage />} />
             <Route path='table' element={<DataTable />} />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
}

function App() {
    

    return (
        <>
        <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
                  <Route index exact element={<Home />} />
                  <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
                  <Route path='contact' element={<ContactUs />} />
                  <Route path='product' element={<OurStore />} />
                      <Route path='product/:id' element={<SingleProduct />} />
                  <Route path='blog' element={<BlogPage />} />
                  <Route path='blog/:id' element={<SingleBlog />} />
                  <Route
                   path='cart'
                   element={<PrivateRoutes><Cart /></PrivateRoutes>}/>
                  <Route 
                                   path='checkout-success/:userId/:transitionId'
                   element={<CheckoutSuccess />}
                  />
                  <Route path='canceled' element={<CheckoutCancel />} />
                  <Route path='orderlists/:id' element={<OrderList />} />
                  <Route path='cancel' element={<CheckoutCancel />} />
                  <Route path='checkout' element={<Checkout />} />
                  <Route path='compare-product' element={<CompareProduct />} />
                  <Route path='wishlist' element={<WishList />} />
                  <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
                  <Route path='signup' element={<SignUp />} />
                  <Route path='forgot-password' element={<ForgotPassword />} />
                  <Route
                   path='reset-password/:id/:uniqueToken'
                   element={<ResetPassword />}
                  />
                  <Route path='shipping-policy' element={<ShippingPolicy />} />
                  <Route path='privacy-policy' element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
                  <Route path='refund-policy' element={<RefundPolicy />} />
                  <Route 
                                    path='term-conditions' 
                                    element={<TermAndConditions />} 
                                  />
                  <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
                    </Route>

                {/* *** Right here *** */}
                  <Route element={<AdminRoutes />}></Route>
                {/* *** Right here *** */}
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
            </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

There is no error or warning in the browser console.

Comment: you are looking for [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet)

Comment: In case you missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] yet, there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Answer (score 0):

`AdminRoutes` renders ***descendent*** routes, so the parent route must append the wildcard matcher `"*"`, or splat, to it's route so the descendent routes can also be matched and rendered.

Since it seems all the admin routes are rendered on parent path `"/admin"` then move this path to the main router and append the splat.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index exact element={<Home />} />
            ...
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/admin/*" element={<AdminRoutes />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
function AdminRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<DashBoard />} />
        ...
        <Route path='table' element={<DataTable />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: Now everything works properly, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @YeMoeLwin Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!